# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table user (///)" via JDBC Statement

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a application. I use Spring Boot, Hibernate and Postgresql

But, when I am trying to run the application, i get this:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table user ..." via JDBC Statement
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at ru.sfedu.diplomabackend.DiplomaBackendApplication.main(DiplomaBackendApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:322) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:279) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
... 35 common frames omitted
```

(and same errors for goal class and diaryday class)

DiaryDay class:

```
 public class DiaryDay implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
@Column(name = "createdDiaryDay")
private Date goalTime;
@Column
private String description;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade =  {CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn(name = "userDiary")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private User userDiary;
```

User class:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
@Column
private String email;
@Column
private String password;
@Column
private String firstName;
@Column
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "createdUser")
private Date userDate;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "users", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Set<Goal> goalSet = new HashSet<>();
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userDiary", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Set<DiaryDay> diaryDays = new HashSet<>();
```

Goal class:

```
public class Goal implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column
    private Date created;
    @Column
    private String description;
    @Column
    private String status;
    @Column
    private Priority priority;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade =  {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "users")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private User users;
```

hibernate configuration file:

```
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">////</property>
    <property name="connection.username">///</property>
    <property name="connection.password">///</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

i have an assumption that there may be an error in ManyToOne or OnetoMany ⊙︿⊙

Answer (score 0):

Error executing DDL "create table user ..."

Most likely you didn't set the user permissions on the database in PostgreSQL, I've got this error many times.

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE database_name TO username;
This might fix it

EDIT:

```
<property name="connection.url">////</property>
<property name="connection.username">///</property>
<property name="connection.password">///</property>
```

I hope you modified these in the real configuration file to match your URL, user and password.

Comment: yes, i modified. but where i should do this: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE database_name TO username; ? (i use heroku for db)

Comment: Check Managing permissions https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql-credentials#creating-a-new-credential

Comment: well, i fixed it by changing name of table in user class :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Good luck with your project.